# Dynamic Kendo UI TreeList

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a json with a param Ids, and For each Id I would like to create a Tree List and bind the data with the given ID. I was wondering what are the ways to achieve it. Especially the columns are identical but how to provide the configuration settings for each dynamically created Tree Lists.

```
{
"id":"1",
"data": "hello",
"status": "inProgress"
},

{
"id":"1",
"data": "hello",
"status": "inProgress"
},

{
"id":"1",
"data": "hello",
"status": "inProgress"
},

{
"id":"2",
"data": "hello",
"status": "inProgress"
},

{
"id":"2",
"data": "hello",
"status": "inProgress"
}
```

Here all the Id 1 data will be part of one TreeList and the ones with Id 2, will be part of another TreeList.

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end have to re-Model my Data to have Parent Child Ids.